# How do I get MongoDB documents to be managed with Spring Data like the EntityManager does with JPA

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am very new to both Spring Data and to MongoDB. I've worked before with Hibernate. I am used to that, when I modify and save a child entity from some other entity, this works perfectly fine. And if I query an entity directly, I will get the very same object (==) as when it is provided as a child entity of another entity.

Now with a UserRepository extending MongoRepository, I get not the same behaviour that I grew fond to. The class is defined as:

```
@Document    
public class User extends Userdetails {
    
    @Id 
    private String id;
    private String username;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Role role;
    @DocumentReference
    private User supervisor;

    //getters and setters...

}
```

Now, I have created two users. One has a TEACHER role and the other has a PUPIL role. The PUPIL has the TEACHER as its 'supervisor'. When I get all the users from the database, the teacher in the list is a different object than the teacher that is the supervisor of the pupil. And if I change a property of the supervisor object of the pupil and save that object, I will get an exception saying there is a duplicate id.

Is there a way to make that the same document in the database is always the same object in JVM memory and there is no need to worry whether I'm persisting the right object?